# servicestack Razor page with relative path in meta refresh not served correctly

Tags: servicestack

this used to work in work in the older versions of service stack (.33).   I'm trying .55 now.

I have a .cshtml page with a relative ~ link, and i also set the WebHostUrl in the EndpointHostConfig.

In the old version both the metarefresh and the href were replaced with the WebHostUrl.  So both were

```
 http://server/baseurl/Incidents.
```

In the newer versions, it only seems the href are.   So the metarefresh is no longer working.   it refreshes to

```
http://server/baseurl/~/Incidents
```

not sure if it can be fixed.

example .cshtml

```
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=~/Incidents">
   </head>
<body> 
<div>
<p>
<center>
    <a href="~/Incidents">View Incidents</a>
</center>
</p>
```

AppHost.cs

```
        SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
            AllowJsonpRequests = true,
            WebHostUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `~` is not valid html or a valid URL.  But you can use the URL extension methods within Razor to  translate the path for you as it understands the tilde.  ASP.NET understands the `~` as the root of your application and will translate it accordingly.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=@Url.Content("~/Incidents")">
</head>
<body> 
    <div>
        <p>
            <center>
                <a href="@Url.Content("~/Incidents")">View Incidents</a>
            </center>
        </p>
```